# auto update list using model

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm running into a problem when implementing this angularjs tutorial. My list does not update when I change the model value.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/3-644

Here's my code.

```
<section class="section-container" id="HomeIndex" ng-app="userApp">
    <article ng-controller="userListController">
        <header>
            <h1>Welcome to my site {{username}}</h1>
        </header>
        <form name="myForm">
            <input name="username" ng-model="username" required/>
        </form>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="User in Users track by $index">{{User.Username}}</li>
        </ul>
    </article>
</section>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var userService = angular.module("userService", ['ngResource']);
    userService.factory('Users', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('@this.Url.Action("FindUser","Home")', {}, {
            query: { method: 'GET', params: { username: $resource.username }, isArray: true }
        });
    } ]);
    var userController = angular.module("userController", []);
    userController.controller('userListController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.Users = [];
        $http({ method: 'GET', url: '@this.Url.Action("GetUser","Home")', params: { username: $scope.username} })
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.Users = data;
        });
    } ]);
    var userApp = angular.module('userApp', ['userController', 'userService']);
//    userApp.filter('array', function () {
//        return function (Users, username) {
//            if (!username)
//                return Users;
//            var res = [];
//            angular.forEach(Users, function (user) {
//                if (user.Username.toLowerCase().indexOf(username) !== -1)
//                    res.push(user);
//            });
//            return res;
//        };
//    });
</script>
```

'
controller

```
public object FindUser(string username, int? max)
            {
                MyWeb.DataContext.UserDataContext mdc= new DataContext.UserDataContext();
                JsonResult js = new JsonResult();
                js.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
                js.Data = mdc.M9s.Where(t => t.UserDomainName.Contains(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username) ? "" : username)).Take(max != null || (max <= 100 && max > 0) ? Convert.ToInt32(max) : 100).Select(t => new { Username = t.UserDomainName.Trim(), JobID = t.JobID, JobFunction = t.JobFunction.Trim() }).ToList();
                return js;
            }
```

Anyone can tell me how to update my list directly when i update the input model?

Comment: what part isn't working in that big block of code?

Comment: @Ronnie my list  not update after i typing some words